# Moving a cocos2d-iphone+box2d boy in one direction

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer, box2d

Please can someone advice me on this.

I have a cocos2d-iphone +box2d body I wish to move only in one direction(movement only from left to right of the iphone screen) using only the accelerometer controls and parallax scrolling. Please how do I do this as at the moment the body moves both to the left and right once the device is tilted. I do not want to use forces or impulse since **I will *NOT* be enabling touch controls.**
This is my accelerometer code :

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration  
*)acceleration {


float32 accelerationFraction = acceleration.y * 6;
if (accelerationFraction < -1) {
    accelerationFraction = -1;
} else if (accelerationFraction > 1) {
  accelerationFraction = 1;
b2Vec2 gravity(-acceleration.y *10, acceleration.x *10);

world->SetGravity( gravity );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You should use mouseJoints. Look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12). There he explains exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks a million for your reply...I have seen the tutorial actually my mistake I am talking about parallax scrolling and the body should move from left to right or the scrolling should be to right on the x axis of the iphone screen(I was a bit sleepy when I posted the question).